# Identify if array list is a file or folder code igniter FTP class

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

OK i am using code igniter FTP class to connect to a server and retrieve the list of files and folders and store that list in an array, Now the issue is how can i identify which array item is a folder and which one is a file.

This is the output

```
 Array
    (
        [list] => Array
            (
                [0] => ./Directory 1 
                [1] => ./Directory 2 
                [2] => ./Directory 3
                [3] => ./New Text Document.txt
            )
```

```
)
```

Comment: is_dir($pathName) will tell you if it's a directory,if_file($pathName) will tell you if it's a file.

Answer (score 0):

try [is_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) and [is_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php).

Also be careful of symlinks, which are neither:
us1.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php

Comment: Not working displays everything as a file even directories. Thank You for the response though, really appreciate it

Comment: Make sure that you are testing absolute paths, not relative ones.

Comment: Also, try making sure that you not checking the same path over and over again, by mistake. (print each file name)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nick J for telling me about file path, finally solved it, credits to you. Here is how i did it

```
$data['list'] = $this->ftp->list_files();

        foreach ($data['list'] as $item){
          $path_parts= pathinfo($item);

          if (isset($path_parts["extension"]))
            {
          echo 'File: '.$item.'
';
          }
            else {
                  echo 'directory:'. $item.'
';
         }
```